# Why does swapping between container IP and alias cause difference in AJAX request?

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

I have a small sample project [located here that illustrates the problem I am seeing](https://github.com/adam-beck/docker-link-cors-problem) when working with a **nginx** + **node** + **host** docker stack.

I have 2 containers:

- A **node** (express) application that simply returns a json object. It is CORs enabled based on [this website](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html). It has it's port published to **host** via `3000:80`
- An **nginx** server that is also CORs enabled based on [this website](http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html). It only serves static content (`index.html` and `main.js` files) from the default location (`/usr/shared/nginx/html`). Its port is published via `8080:80`.

When running the containers individually from **host** I can access the node server and see the JSON object being returned. When I access the nginx server, I see my `index.html` and the javascript code from `main.js` runs.

Now I have the node app container linked to the nginx server container. From inside my `main.js` file of the **nginx** container, I attempt to access the server at `http://nodeapp/api`. I am seeing a CORs error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://nodeapp/api. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

The strange thing is, the **response header** indicates it is coming from nginx and **not** my express application as I would expect. The nginx container is also not logging anything.

#### Things that worked

- If I change the url for the XMLHttpRequest to the node container's IP (say 172.17.0.2) it works as expected **and** the response header indicates it is coming from the express server. In my `/etc/hosts` file there is an entry:
  `172.17.0.2    nodeapp abc123ContainerId quickserve_nodeapp_run_1`
- When I `curl` the node container from an interactive tty container it also works as expected.
- If I load the node container and use `http-server` (server on host) it works as expected **and** the response header indicates it is coming from the express server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27371390/6309 wouldn't help?

Comment: [I have CORs enabled on my server though](https://github.com/adam-beck/docker-link-cors-problem/blob/master/default.conf)

Comment: I agree. I meant by my answer below to enable it at the docker daemon level.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it has an incluence, that [old thread (2013)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/-tdqJsEDsF0) mentioned a cor option on the docker daemon.
Nowadays (Q4 2015), the [docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/) includes:

```
--api-cors-header=""                   Set CORS headers in the remote API
```

> To set cross origin requests to the remote api please give values to `--api-cors-header` when running Docker in daemon mode. Set * (asterisk) allows all, default or blank means CORS disabled

```
$ docker -d -H="192.168.1.9:2375" --api-cors-header="http://foo.bar"
```

That might be a setting to use in your case.

Comment: Even with my daemon started with this option I'm getting the same error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://nodeapp/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`. I will look further into the discussion on the thread for any helpful info. Thank you for pointing me to it.

Comment: @adam-b-infinity OK, it was worth checking.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find out how to enable the CORS header?