# Error making http get request from flutter-web to fastapi server

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, fastapi

I have a method which calls the get method

```
Future<Case> getCaseDetails(int caseId) async {
  final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String baseUrl = sharedPreferences.getString("baseUrl");
  final response = await http.get(
      "$baseUrl" + "/case/" + caseId.toString() + '/details',
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
  return Case.fromMap(json.decode(response.body));
}
```

and it is implemented as such

```
FutureBuilder<Case>(
    future: getCaseDetails(1),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Card(
                child: Text(snapshot.data.query),);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
)
```

The error is simply displayed as `XMLHttpRequest error` and no description. I can see that the request is being handled at the server side and i've also added `CORSMiddleware` to the server as mentioned in related posts but that did not fix the issue.

What could be the issue here and how do i resolve it?

Comment: Did you try to call the API with a different method? By the browser, via PostMan?

Comment: yes, the API works fine with the browser with swagger ui

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['XMLHttpRequest cannot load' Error on HTTP Requests from Dart client to local Dart docker server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369722/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-error-on-http-requests-from-dart-client-to-local-da)

Answer (score 2):

Posting my own answer. It was a CORS error as i hadn't allowed the client origin. Setting allow_origins=["*"] fixed the issue.

```
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```